# java getMethod() on generic type

Tags: java, generics, reflection

i want use reflection on generic type

i have this class

```
package it.ciro.service;

import it.ciro.dao.SysMyAbDao;
import org.apache.log4j.Logger;

import java.io.Serializable;
import java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException;
import java.lang.reflect.Method;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;

/**
 * Created by ciro on 09/12/2016.
 */
public class SelectOption<E extends Serializable> {

    private SysMyAbDao dao;
    private Class<E> entity;
    private ArrayList<Class<E>> entityAll;
    private Map<String,String> optionList = new HashMap<String,String>();
    protected Logger logger;

    public SelectOption(SysMyAbDao dao,Class<E> entity,String idName, String labelName ){
        logger  = Logger.getLogger(this.getClass());

        this.dao = dao;
        this.entity = entity;
        entityAll = dao.findAll();
        try{
            Method idMethod = this.entity.getMethod(idName);
            Method labelMethod = this.entity.getClass().getMethod(labelName);
            for (Class<E> single : entityAll) {
                optionList.put((String)idMethod.invoke(single),(String)labelMethod.invoke(single));
            }
        }catch (NoSuchMethodException ex){
            ex.printStackTrace();
            logger.error(ex.getMessage());
        } catch (InvocationTargetException e) {
            logger.error(e.getMessage());
        } catch (IllegalAccessException e) {
            logger.error(e.getMessage());
        }
    }

    public Map<String, String> getOptionList() {
        return optionList;
    }
}
```

and in my controller

```
SelectOption<GeoProvince> selectOption = new SelectOption(geoRegionDao,GeoRegion.class,"idGeoRegion","name");
```

but i get

```
java.lang.NoSuchMethodException: java.lang.Class.idGeoRegion()
```

java search on generic type e not on type that I use in constructor

I expect the search to be made about the type I spend in controller. In GeoRegion class the method exists.

this is SysMyAbDao

```
public abstract class SysMyAbDao<T, E, Id extends Serializable> {
    protected String message;
    protected Boolean status;
    protected T t ;
    protected Logger logger;
    protected Long totalRow;
    private Class<T> type;

    public SysMyAbDao(Class<T> type){
        this.type = type;
    }
    .....
```

GeoRegion class

```
public class GeoRegion  implements java.io.Serializable {

     private int idRegion;
     private String name;
     private String code;
     private Set<GeoProvince> geoProvinces = new HashSet<GeoProvince>(0);
     private Set<GeoCity> geoCities = new HashSet<GeoCity>(0);

    public GeoRegion() {
    }


    public GeoRegion(int idRegion) {
        this.idRegion = idRegion;
    }
    public GeoRegion(int idRegion, String name, String code, Set<GeoProvince> geoProvinces, Set<GeoCity> geoCities) {
       this.idRegion = idRegion;
       this.name = name;
       this.code = code;
       this.geoProvinces = geoProvinces;
       this.geoCities = geoCities;
    }

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name="id_region", unique=true, nullable=false)
    public int getIdRegion() {
        return this.idRegion;
    }

    public void setIdRegion(int idRegion) {
        this.idRegion = idRegion;
    }


    @Column(name="name")
    public String getName() {
        return this.name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }


    @Column(name="code", unique=true)
    public String getCode() {
        return this.code;
    }

    public void setCode(String code) {
        this.code = code;
    }

    @OneToMany(fetch=FetchType.LAZY, mappedBy="geoRegion")
    public Set<GeoProvince> getGeoProvinces() {
        return this.geoProvinces;
    }

    public void setGeoProvinces(Set<GeoProvince> geoProvinces) {
        this.geoProvinces = geoProvinces;
    }

    @OneToMany(fetch=FetchType.LAZY, mappedBy="geoRegion")
    public Set<GeoCity> getGeoCities() {
        return this.geoCities;
    }

    public void setGeoCities(Set<GeoCity> geoCities) {
        this.geoCities = geoCities;
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you post the code for `GeoRegion` class ?

Comment: @javaguy posted

Answer (score 2):

You have an extra `getClass()` in this line:

```
Method labelMethod = this.entity.getClass().getMethod(labelName);
```

In fact, you are calling `getClass()` on the `Class<E>` object. And as the class of `Class<E>` is not `E` but `java.lang.Class` you get the `NoSuchMethodException` you posted.

Also the instance which you are invoking your method on (`single` in your case), should be of type `E` and not of type `Class<E>`.

Overall you would end up with something like:

```
public SelectOption(SysMyAbDao<E, ?, ? extends Serializable> dao,
                    Class<E> entityClass, 
                    String idName, 
                    String labelName) { 
    this.dao = dao;
    this.entityClass = entityClass;
    this.entityAll = dao.findAll(); // make sure your SysMyAbDao<E, ?, ?>#findAll() returns a Collection<E>
    try{
        Method idMethod = this.entityClass.getMethod(idName);
        Method labelMethod = this.entityClass.getMethod(labelName);
        for (E instance : entityAll) {
            optionList.put((String)idMethod.invoke(instance),(String)labelMethod.invoke(instance));
        }
    } catch (NoSuchMethodException ex){
        ...
    }
}
```

Comment: not work beacuse SysMyAbDao is abstract and generic class. edit question with code

Comment: @ciro: Then you should fix the type of your `dao`-parameter accordingly. I assumed that the first generic type is the one that is returned by the `findAll()`-method in the changed code above.

Comment: in which way please?

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to invoke your method on `single`, which is a `Class` object.

I don't see any instances of `GeoRegion` in this code.  But in order for this to work, you need to use this method on one of them:

```
E instance = getSomeObjectFromSomewhere();
optionList.put((String)idMethod.invoke(instance),(String)labelMethod.invoke(instance));
```

Comment: i don't know At prior if Class i GeoRegion or other clasd